# Code that recognises a keypress in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, keypress, python-3.3

Is there anyway for python 3 to recognise a keypress? For example, if the user pressed the up arrow, the program would do one thing whereas if the down arrow was pressed, the program would do something else.

I do not mean the input() function where the user has to press enter after the keypress , I mean where the program recognises the keypress as some as it was pressed.

Is this question too confusing? xD

Answer (score 2):

Python has a [**keyboard**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyboard) module with many features. You Can Use It In Both *Shell* and *Console*. 
Install it, perhaps with this command:

```
pip3 install keyboard
```

Then use it in code like:

```
import keyboard #Using module keyboard
while True:  #making a loop
    try:  #used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
        if keyboard.is_pressed('up'): #if key 'up' is pressed.You can use right,left,up,down and others
            print('You Pressed A Key!')
            break #finishing the loop
        else:
            pass
    except:
        break  #if user pressed other than the given key the loop will break
```

You can set it to multiple Key Detection:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('up') or keyboard.is_pressed('down') or keyboard.is_pressed('left') or keyboard.is_pressed('right'):
    #then do this
```

You Can Also Do Something like:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('up') and keyboard.is_pressed('down'):
    #then do this
```

It Also Detect Key For The Whole Windows.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a gui program,

If using the built-in gui module Tkinter, you can use bind to connect a function to a keypress.

```
main.bind('<Up>', userUpkey)
```

Where userUpKey is a function defined in the current scope.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer (I'm not actually writing a program, this was just a general query) but do you know if it's possible in the command line (not GUI)?

Comment: I would look at curses. I have not personally used it, So I won't attempt an example.